# How to neglect fields with null value while updating Elasticsearch document?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

When i tried to update a document in elasticsearch without specifying  some fields,it updates that fields to null . Here is the code i used.

```
public class DocumentModel {
@Id
private String id;
private Integer name;
private String gender;
private String url;
private String documentID;
------------------
------------------
getters and setters
}
```

Code used for indexing document is :

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create();
String json = gson.toJson(documentModel);
IndexRequest indexRequest = new IndexRequest(indexName, typeName, documentModel.getId());
indexRequest.source(json);
UpdateRequest updateRequest = new UpdateRequest(indexName, typeName, documentModel.getId());
updateRequest.doc(json);
updateRequest.upsert(indexRequest);
updateRequest.fields("documentID");
UpdateResponse updateResponse = elasticsearchTemplate.getClient().update(updateRequest).actionGet();
```

Suppose the input(documentModel) is(indexing the document first time):

```
{"id":1,"name":"tom","gender":"male","url":"http://www.google.com","documentID":1}
```

it will index as :

```
{
      "_index": "index",
      "_type": "type",
      "_id": "1",
      "_score": 1,
      "_source": {
             "name":"tom",
             "gender":"male",
             "url":"http://www.google.com",
             "documentID":1
      }
    }
```

But when i tried to update same document with input :

```
{"id":1,"name":"archana","gender":"female"}
```

it will update as :

```
{
          "_index": "index",
          "_type": "type",
          "_id": "1",
          "_score": 1,
          "_source": {
                 "name":"archana",
                 "gender":"female",
                 "url":null,
                 "documentID":null
          }
        }
```

The problem is fields that are not given as input (eg 'url','documentID') is set to null while updating document.but i want that field remains to be with the old value unless the value is not null(eg as "url":"http://www.google.com").

Answer (score 3):

I think your problem is `serializeNulls`. [The docs say](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html#serializeNulls--):

> Configure Gson to serialize null fields. By default, Gson omits all fields that are null during serialization.

I think that means you're sending a request to Elasticsearch that looks something like:

```
POST /index/type/1/_update
{
  "doc": {
     "name":"archana",
     "gender":"female",
     "url":null,
     "documentID":null
  }
}
```

Which tells Elasticsearch you want to write over those values with `null`. If you don't want to write over them, you need to leave them completely out of the request, which I think you can accomplish just by getting rid of the `serializeNulls()` call.

This is something you have to handle in your code, or in a scripted update (though I can't think of a reason you would want to do that, unless you don't control the code making the request), or you could write a plugin to add this behavior.

Comment: Thanks.But i want an option in ES that avoid updating null values

Comment: I don't think that's possible, except with a scripted update (which doesn't make a lot of sense to me), or if you write and install a plugin to add this behavior. Maybe you can update the question to explain more about why you can't handle this in your code and someone is more likely to come up with an alternative solution that meets your needs?

Answer (score 0):

Doing delta updates is supported by Elastic by using the _update Rest API call, so I assume the Java API should do the same if you do

```
updateRequest.update(indexRequest)
```

instead of

```
updateRequest.upsert(indexRequest)
```

Note that an explicit update would fail if the document don't exist, so you would need to check that before issuing the update command.

Providing Elastic and Java API versions would be useful

Comment: In my case, i need to index document if not exist and update if exist in single query

Comment: Yes, that is what will happen on a normal post to a specific ID. But if you're going to do a partial update or a fresh insert you will have to know if the document exists or not, and I don't think that can be done in a single operation in ElasticSearch. In ES you never really update documents, they can only be added and removed, and any "update" will create a new entry and mark the old one for deletion. Is there a reason why you can't check if the document exists before issuing create or update?